# Xuggler and libfdk-aac

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, xuggler

I'm new in Xuggler and I want to transcode mp3 audios to aac plus audios using libfdk-aac. I have compiled ffmpeg and enabled the libfdk-aac library. When I try to transcode an audio file using libfdk-aac from the command line all works fine.

I want to use libfdk-aac from Xuggler and since Xuggler is a ffmpeg wrapper I think it should be possible to use libfdk-aac. I have used the method getInstalledCodecs from class com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec in order to get the id of the libfdk codec, in class
com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder I have set the codec ID and it seems that the libfdk codec is being used, nevertheless I need to activate the aac_he profile (profile option in ffmpeg), I have tried to use the setProperty method in IStreamCoder class but I always get a negative return value and files are always transcoded in normal aac.

Is there any way to activate the aac_he profile from Xuggler?

Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile Xuggler because xuggler comes with its own ffmpeg if I am not mistaken.